# Mobile app design size

Tags: website-design, interface-design, mobile, adobe-xd, figma

**Mobile app design size**

What size is more appropriate and common for mobile application design in XD Figma software?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I think this is more a UX design question. Might be better on [User Experience Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) to be honest.  Also, mobile devices all have different size displays. There's no common size.  Your interface design should be fluid/responsive so it fits any device.

Comment: See this [related answer to a similar question on UX Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9944/whats-the-average-screen-size-of-a-handheld-android-tablet-device-any-wireframi/10007#10007)

Comment: That's right, thanks